# Move model out of service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, viewmodel, angularjs-service, angularjs-factory

I am a bit new to angularjs.  I have a service that works fine.  however I would like to move the model (the patient model) out of the service and put it in a separtate javascript file. not quite sure how to do this. I'm guessing I need a factory or service of some type?

this is my patient.service.js

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('beincharge.patient')
    .factory('patientDataService', patientDataService);

patientDataService.$inject = ['$http'];

function patientDataService($http) {
    var service = {
        getData: getData
    };

    return service;

    //////////

    function getData() {
        // I would like to move this model into a separate js file
       function patient(d) {

            this.Status = d.Status;
            this.ImageUrl = d.ImageUrl;
            this.PersonId = d.PersonId;
            this.LastName = d.LastName;
            this.MiddleName = d.MiddleName;
            this.FirstName = d.FirstName;
        }
        // end I would like to move this model into a separate js file


        var data = [
            {
                "Status": "Active",
                "ImageUrl": "http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/9/",
                "PersonId": 1,
                "LastName": "Pratt",
                "MiddleName": "B",
                "FirstName": "Allie"
            },
            {
                "Status": 'Active',
                "ImageUrl": "http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/3/",
                "PersonId": 1,
                "LastName": "Pratt",
                "MiddleName": "B",
                "FirstName": "Allie"

            }];

             return  getPatientList(data);

             function getPatientList(data) {
                 var a = [];
                 angular.forEach(data, function (d, i) {
                     a.push(new patient(d));
                 })
                 return a;
             }



    }
}
```

so I would like to move the model into a file called patient.model.js

```
  (function () {
    function patient(d) {
        this.Status = d.Status;
        this.ImageUrl = d.ImageUrl;
        this.PersonId = d.PersonId;
        this.LastName = d.LastName;
        this.MiddleName = d.MiddleName;
        this.FirstName = d.FirstNa
    }
    return patient;
}());
```

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do. Most times a service *is* a model in cases like this one. You've already got a unit that deals with data and contains business logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a factory provider and should be like this:

```
angular
    .module('beincharge.patient')
    .factory('Patient', function() {
         return function(d){
             this.Status = d.Status;
             this.ImageUrl = d.ImageUrl;
             this.PersonId = d.PersonId;
             this.LastName = d.LastName;
             this.MiddleName = d.MiddleName;
             this.FirstName = d.FirstName
         }
     });
```

and then in the Service you can use like this:

```
angular
    .module('beincharge.patient')
    .factory('patientDataService', patientDataService);

patientDataService.$inject = ['$http', 'Patient'];

function patientDataService($http, Patient){
    console.log(new Patient({ Status: 'active' }));
}
```

You can see the full example below:

https://jsfiddle.net/9af3qys7/1/

Comment: thanks that looks alot like what I am after. I will it give it a shot this evening and award bounty if everything looks good.

Answer (score 0):

if all you want is a model you can instantiate and reuse then create a simple JavaScript object like this, in a patientModel.js file:

```
 function PatientModel() {
        this.Status = "";
        this.ImageUrl = "";
        this.PersonId = "";
        this.LastName = "";
        this.MiddleName = "";
        this.FirstName = "";
    }
```

Make sure this file is loaded before the controllers or services where you want to use it.

you can then instantiate it like this:

```
var patient = new PatientModel();
```

Of course you change the constructor function to have some parameters if that's what you need so you can pass through whatever you have in your d parameter.

This will work for you as long as all you need is some simple and reusable models. The advantage is that you can keep using them in your tests as well rather than relying on hardcoded json objects.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to write javascript in java style, I don't see any need to create patient model here, the response/data in your case is exactly the same as patient object. A much simpler implementation would be

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('beincharge.patient')
    .factory('patientDataService', patientDataService);

patientDataService.$inject = ['$http'];

function patientDataService($http) {
    var service = {
        getData: getData
    };
    return service;

    this.getData = function () {
        var data = [
        {
            "Status": "Active",
            "ImageUrl": "http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/9/",
            "PersonId": 1,
            "LastName": "Pratt",
            "MiddleName": "B",
            "FirstName": "Allie"
        },
        {
            "Status": 'Active',
            "ImageUrl": "http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/3/",
            "PersonId": 1,
            "LastName": "Pratt",
            "MiddleName": "B",
            "FirstName": "Allie"

        }];
        return data;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here you can move  app.service(..) into patient.model.js

```js
 var app = angular.module('beincharge_patient',[]);

 app.service('patientData',function(){
   var getP = function(d) {
      this.Status = d.Status;
      this.ImageUrl = d.ImageUrl;
      this.PersonId = d.PersonId;
      this.LastName = d.LastName;
      this.MiddleName = d.MiddleName;
      this.FirstName = d.FirstName;
    }
    var service = {
      getP: getP
    }
    return service; 
 });

app.factory('patientDataService',['$http','patientData',function($http,patientData){
  
    var getData = function() {
      var data = [{
          "Status": "Active",
          "ImageUrl": "http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/9/",
          "PersonId": 1,
          "LastName": "Pratt",
          "MiddleName": "B",
          "FirstName": "Allie"
        },
        {
          "Status": 'Active',
          "ImageUrl": "http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/3/",
          "PersonId": 1,
          "LastName": "Pratt",
          "MiddleName": "B",
          "FirstName": "Allie"
        }
      ];      
       var getPatientList = function(data) {
        var a = [];
        angular.forEach(data, function (d, i) {
            a.push(new patientData.getP(d));
        })
        return a;
      }
       return  getPatientList(data);
    }
    var service = {
      getData: getData
    };
    return service;
}]);

 app.controller('beincharge_patient_Controller',    ['$scope','patientDataService',function($scope,patientDataService){   
   $scope.temp=patientDataService.getData();
 }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.11/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="beincharge_patient" ng-controller="beincharge_patient_Controller">
  <br/>
  {{temp}}
</div>
```